# Is this the correct way to use two loops in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I am trying to check two things here, with two different `for loops`. One if a element has a `attribute`, that works! And the second loop should check if the alt tag is actually empty. I figured passing the first `iterator` value to the second would dispatch the second loop. But that doesn't work! Can someone help me out with this one?

```
function altChecker() {
    var doc = document,

        getStartedBtn = doc.getElementById('getStartedBtn');

        EventUtility.addHandler(getStartedBtn, 'click', function() {

        var all = doc.getElementsByTagName("IMG");

        console.log('success!');

        for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
            if (all[i].hasAttribute('alt')) {
                console.log('Yes, this has a ' + all[i].nodeName + ' tag!');
            } else {
                console.log('Sorry ' + all[i].nodeName + ' tag, doesn\'t have an alt tag!');
            }

        }
        for (var j = i, max2 = all; j < max2; j++) {
            if(! $(all[j]).attr('alt')){
                console.log('This is empty');
            } else {
                console.log('This aint');
            }
        };

    });
}
```

Comment: What `iterator` are you talking about? Btw, see the difference between `max = all.length` and `max2 = all`

Comment: Also you should initialise `j` just with `0` as always, not with `i`, which is `== max` at the time the second loop is entered.

Comment: where are `max` and `max2` declared? and why do you need 2 loops for this?

Comment: also just consider using `all[j].alt` instead of `$(all[j]).attr('alt')` to avoid completely unnecessary (and slow) jQuery calls

Comment: What about just one loop?

Comment: @WhiteHat - after the iterators, `var i = 0, max = all.length;` There is a comma. Thanks for responding. How would you simplify it to one `loop`?

Comment: @Kasper: How would you just handle it with one loop?

Comment: @Alnitak - Thanks, but that didn't work.

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz by itself it's insufficient, but you have other problems with your loops (per some of the answers given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think 2 loops are required

```
function altChecker() {
    var doc = document,

    getStartedBtn = doc.getElementById('getStartedBtn');

    EventUtility.addHandler(getStartedBtn, 'click', function() {

        var all = doc.getElementsByTagName("IMG");

        console.log('success!');

        for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
            if (all[i].hasAttribute('alt')) {
              if (all[i].alt === '') {
                  console.log('this has a ' + all[i].nodeName + ' tag BUT it is empty!');
              } else {
                  console.log('Yes, this has a ' + all[i].nodeName + ' tag and it is NOT empty!');
              }
            } else {
                console.log('Sorry ' + all[i].nodeName + ' tag, doesn\'t have an alt tag!');
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one loop. Check for the value of alt after checking if the attribute exists.

*Note that `alt` is a standard property of the `img` tag but not `div`.  In the example I used `.getAttribute` for the the non-standard property.  If I used `img` tags then `.getAttribute` could be replaced with `.alt` since that's a standard property of the tag. see comments.*

```js
function altChecker() {
  var out = [];
  var doc = document;
  var all = doc.getElementsByTagName("div");

  for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
    var id = all[i].id;
    if (all[i].hasAttribute('alt')) {
      out.push(id + ' has alt');
      var value = all[i].getAttribute('alt');
      if (value != "") {
        out.push(id + ' alt="' + value + '"');
      } else {
        out.push(id + ' alt is empty');
      }
    } else {
      out.push(id + ' does not have alt');
    }
  }
  doc.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out.join("\n");
}

altChecker();
```

```html
<div id='a' alt='foo'>-</div>
<div id='b' alt='bar'>-</div>
<div id='c' alt=''>-</div>
<div id='d'>-</div>

<pre id='output'></pre>
```

Comment: there's no need for a `.getAttribute` call when the attribute being examined is a standard property of that element - you can juse use `all[i].alt`.   You do need to use `.hasAttribute` if you to check whether the attribute actually exists in the HTML markup, though, since the default value for `.alt` is an empty string.

Comment: @Alnitak I switched it and it worked but strangely .alt started returning "undefined" after the second try.  It may be a bug with the browser but .getAttribute seems to be consistent so I switched it back. I'm using FF 40.0.3

Comment: my comment applied to the OP's use of an `<img>` tag for which `alt` is a standard property but in your example you've used `<div>` elements instead.  I don't believe it's guaranteed at all that browsers will generate properties for unexpected attributes on an element.

Comment: @Alnitak Ah that makes sense now.  I was wondering why `id` didn't have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your .length property in the 2nd if:

`max2 = all`

Should be `max2 = all.length`

Answer (score 0):

If you intended to loop though the all collection twice, you missed the length property on all in the second loop, and you need to start the j variable from 0.

```
for (var j = i, max2 = all; j < max2; j++) {
```

should be:

```
for (var j = 0, max2 = all.length; j < max2; j++) {
```

The two loops are completely independent and just iterate over the all collection; you write them in exactly the same way.

Mistakes like that are why I usually use functional idioms for looping:

```
$.each(all, function(idx, each){...});
```